# touchSlider doesn't work when load page dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages which are using touchSlider(jquery library). Both are working in separate pages. But when I want to load them dynamically to index.html, the library can't work. Here is my html code and js code.
Thank you so much!

index.js

```
    $("#div1").on("click", function() {
            $.getScript( "js/jquery.touchSlider.min.js", function() {
                $("#main-content").html("");
                $("#main-content").load("page2.html");
                $('#gallery2').touchSlider({
                    animation: 'js',
                    mode: 'shift',
                    offset: 'auto'
                });                     
    });

$("#div2").on("click", function() {
        $.getScript( "js/jquery.touchSlider.min.js", function() {
            $("#main-content").html("");
            $("#main-content").load("page1.html");
            $('#gallery1').touchSlider({
                animation: 'js',
                mode: 'shift',
                offset: 'auto'
            });                         

    });
```

index.html

```
<div>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

page1.html

```
<div class="page1">
  <div id="gallery1">slider1</div>
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div class="page2">
  <div id="gallery2">slider2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the code is executed before the plugin is successfully loaded. So you have to use the callback function in your `.load()` method:

**Edited:** To prevent the reload of the plugin I created a third function to do the functionally. This logic can be improved, but I think you can work so:

```
$("#div1").on("click", function() {
    if( $.fn.touchSlider === undefined ){
        $.getScript( "js/jquery.touchSlider.min.js", function() {
            loadSlider(2, 2);
        });           
    }
    else {
        loadSlider(2, 2);
    }
});

$("#div2").on("click", function() {
    if( $.fn.touchSlider === undefined ){
        $.getScript( "js/jquery.touchSlider.min.js", function() {
            loadSlider(1, 1);
        });           
    }
    else {
        loadSlider(1, 1);
    }
});

function loadSlider(page_number, gallery_number){
    $("#main-content").html("").load("page" + page_number + ".html", function(){
        $('#gallery' + gallery_number).touchSlider({
            animation: 'js',
            mode: 'shift',
            offset: 'auto'
        });                         
    });
}
```

Check jQuery `.load` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried your method, but the problem is the slider in "#div2" still not working. The slider in #div1 is working well.

Comment: Well I didn't see too much all the code but now I see that we are loading two times the plugin, so I'll change a little bit the above code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure what happened here, I used nodejs server first but none of the methods worked, but your first method is working well when I switch my server to xampp. I think the problem is solved! Thank you!